# malformed redirect_uri, even though it matches AllowedRedirectUris value

Tags: xamarin.forms, identityserver4

I'm banging my head trying to finish up a Xamarin app connecting to IdentityServer4.  I have three methods of authentication: Google, Facebook, and direct login on the ASP.NET app/API.  The first two are currently working.  The last one works for Android.  iOS will not work.  The redirect_uri is "com.myapp.mobile" (no colon or slashes, unlike Android, because the iOS browser won't allow it.  This was added to the AllowedRedirectUris.  When the browser loads the IS4 login page, I get a malformed redirect_uri.  Please see the raw data.  How do these not match?

`malformed redirect_uri: "com.myapp.mobile"`
`AuthorizeRequestValidationLog { ClientId: "tcpmobileclient", ClientName: "Top Chrome Pro Mobile Client", RedirectUri: null, AllowedRedirectUris: ["com.myapp.mobile", "com.myapp.mobile://callback"], SubjectId: "anonymous", ResponseType: null, ResponseMode: null, GrantType: null, RequestedScopes: "", State: null, UiLocales: null, Nonce: null, AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses: null, DisplayMode: null, PromptMode: "", MaxAge: null, LoginHint: null, SessionId: null, Raw: [("response_type": "code id_token"), ("nonce": "YjbXSWGHC3lCsUrRJQAiJw"), ("state": "IbYJo3pqC76LExrAdw-Udw"), ("code_challenge": "oemC7UzZO7lyDv63iDnuVHQQZCmN4bsDAOsNmEr50pI"), ("code_challenge_method": "S256"), ("client_id": "tcpmobileclient"), ("scope": "openid profile email offline_access IdentityServerApi"), ("redirect_uri": "com.myapp.mobile")] }`

Edit: just confirmed this is now happening on Android as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining because it's not actually a valid URI and the validation logic checks that:

See line 323 here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3ff3b46698f48f164ab1b54d124125d63439f9d0/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/AuthorizeRequestValidator.cs

Comment: Yes, @HelluvaEngineer the problem is related to the backend, you need to check the redirect_uri .

Comment: Doesn't that break many mobile apps that are authenticating via browser?  Her's an example very similar to what I'm doing:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android

Comment: Just to confirm I changed it to a a well, formatted URI.  That allows me to log in.  Then it redirects me to the requested webpage, which is invalid.  I need it to redirect back to my mobile application.  I swear this was working before, and I might attempt to roll-back IS4.

Comment: The authentication API that launches the web flow will be able to intercept the URI you specify. What mechanism are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by changing the redirect URI to `com.myapp.mobile://` Sorry for the confusion on my part.